# WPF - Focus second window by clicking a button

Tags: wpf, window, focus

I'm creating a `WPF` application and I have 3 Windows (`MainWindow`, `Window2` and `Window3`). When I start the project `Window2` loads right after my `MainWindow` is loaded. And when I click a `Button`, `Window3` opens

```
Window3 w3 = new Window3(this, this.window2);
w3.ShowDialog();
```

but I'm not able to do things (click controls etc.) in `Window2`, I know that `ShowDialog()` method is disabling other open Windows but is there a possibility to access using those controls in Window2. How could I get access to `Window2`'s functionalities when `Window3` is open?
PS.(Sorry for asking a stupid question but I'm beginner in WPF)!

Comment: share the code.

Comment: Which part of code is enought to share? Because I have a lot of things...

Comment: how you are opening the windows?

Comment: I just want to access Window2 back by clicking a button in Window3

Comment: then you could do like this: yourWindowName.Focus(); or find the control in Window2 that you want to focus and calll Focus() method on it.

Comment: Window2 is open all the time and I have added in to button click event `myWindowName.Focus(); ` but it did not help

Comment: is the window focussable?

Comment: Show code that opens Window3.

Comment: `Focusable="True" IsEnabled="True"`

Answer (score 0):

You can access `System.Windows.Application` static class's `Windows` collection to have list of all currently opened windows. Then you can iterate the collection and find your window by type or some other criteria. One way would be:

```
var window3 = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window3>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Edit:

In comments to the question you stated that you were opening window using `w3.Show()` method. That opens window in **non modal** way. While after editing the question w3.ShowDialog() opens the window in **modal** way. 
You can learn more about modal windows at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773(v=vs.110).aspx)

> A modal dialog box is displayed by a function when the function needs additional data from a user to continue. Because the function depends on the modal dialog box to gather data, the modal dialog box also prevents a user from activating other windows in the application while it remains open.

So to be able to switch focus between windows they should be **non modal** and opened using `Show` method instead of `ShowDialog`.